# WPF: Passing an TabItem control to controller class

Tags: c#, wpf, controller, tabcontrol, tabitem

I'm using WPF and the `TabControl` as my `Menu`.  This generates a lot of code behind code because one file is controlling all the user actions. Then I was thinking that I could use a `Controller` class for every `TabItem`. I used it and it works, but I don't like the outcome.  I have to use the `FindName()` method on the `TabItem` that I pass to the `Controller` and it generates some ugly code that can be hard to debug (in my opinion at least).

So is there any way to pass the `TabItem` so that I can find the Controls on the xaml page in my `Controller`?

For example I have `TabItem1`, `TabItem2` and `TabItem3`. Each containing a page for the user to use. Then I want to pass `TabItem1` to controller `TabItem1Controller`. At the moment I'm doing it this way:

```
public TurbineController(TabItem tab)
    {
        _client = tab;
    }
```

But then I have to use the `FindName()` method.

Is my request possible?

Comment: Can you not keep a reference of the TabItems in the controller via an array?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you use MVVM approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it backward, at least to the MVVM approach. The controller (TurbineContoller) shouldn't reference the view (TabItem), the view should reference the controller. Create a collection of controllers and databind the collection to a tabcontrol. The datacontext of each tab will be the controller which the tab will databind to.